# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close, incorrectly-closed

I came upon this question ([If Windows 10 "upgrade" affects GRUB2 and screws up my dual boot with Ubuntu will I have to completely wipe my computer and start from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576590/will-windows-10-upgrade-affect-grub2-and-screw-up-my-dual-boot-with-ubuntu)) from Google and I spent five minutes trying to figure out why it was closed. I still have no idea.

Yes, at the time it was was asked, Windows 10 wasn't released so there couldn't be a 100% accurate answer to this specific case, but that's true of any question. There can be a example of what was the case with Windows 8 or 8.1 and that would also likely occur with Windows 10.

Even @Whaaaaaat , who voted to close, posted an answer, in the comments! The third comment gives a reasonable prediction based on past behavior.

So as this comment-answer was not primarily opinion-based whatsoever, why was it closed? (I'm not trying to get it reopened or anything, just want to know the reasoning.)

Answer (score 5):

> There can be a example of what was the case with Windows 8 or 8.1 and that would also likely occur with Windows 10.

A question on something that's not out yet is just asking for speculation. So make the question about Windows 8 or 8.1. Oh wait! There already is one:  [Will upgrading Windows 8 to 8.1 affect Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360465/will-upgrading-windows-8-to-8-1-affect-ubuntu)

We don't even deal with problems in pre-release versions of **Ubuntu** here, I see no reason why a pre-release version of Windows should be entertained.

Comment: A good answer to the question should have then been a link to the question about upgrading 8 to 8.1, and/or a quick description of the answer to that question. Yeah it's technically speculation, but so is the typical "here's what's not working, how can I fix it" question. That type of question is usually given a speculative answer based on the facts that are available. This question should have been treated the same. This question could have easily been answer based on history, with just as minimal speculation as in all askubuntu questions, so why was it closed?

Comment: @Prime624 there are good questions and good answers. We want those, not speculation. That something can be easily answered is not a criterion for being good.

Comment: The question has 8 upvotes, so obviously it's helpful to some other people. Theres no such thing as a and question. If multiple people have the same question, it must be at least somewhat useful. As I practically spelled out above, it's not speculation any more than every question.

Comment: @Prime624 There are deleted questions which have dozens of upvotes and thousands of views. Doesn't mean a thing. If that is as much speculation as any other, then your standards of what constitutes speculation are very low.

Comment: @Prime624 And anybody who says "there is no such thing as a bad question" is not worth talking to, as far as I am concerned. EOD.